# PHP socket expired after few minutes

Tags: php, sockets

I tested this code on my VPS server:
https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/

I start the server via terminal php -q server.php OR nohup php -q server.php and in both cases my socket closes after 5 to 10 minutes. How to automatically open socket when closed, or how to keep socket open? I tried to use cron job but the result was not good.

Comment: you need to ping/pong every now and then else it does close, its normal

Comment: It also depends on your PHP settings - maximum script execution time, etc.  One workaround is to have the PHP script detect if it is approaching maximum and then spawn another PHP process to replace itself.  You could then also have a script run every so often to look for your PHP process.  If it doesn't exist, you could relaunch the script.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ok i understand that, but how to relaunch socket automatically when closed. I tried the Ratchet too